Python application cannot copy files to network shares when running in Jenkins
I have an application that is supposed to write to a network share.  When I run the job locally(Windows), the files are copied over correctly.  The log contains the file path:
\\ABCfile\ReconciliationReports\QA\2024-07-18-15-35_InventoryReport.xlsx

When this same job is run in Jenkins, the log shows this path:
\\ABCfile\ReconciliationReports/QA/2024-07-18-23-21_InventoryReport.xlsx

The file is not copied over though and there is no error.  The slashes are different too.  I'm not sure if my issue is that the Jenkins path has mixed slashes.
I've read that the backwards and forward slashes are interchangable, but I'm at a loss to understand why the file is not being copied.
The code is below.  I've included the value each line is resolving to when I run the job locally.
self.working_path = os.path.join(self.destination_filepath,self.env.value)
self.working_path = \\ABCfile\ReconciliationReports\QA\                 

source_filename = os.path.basename(self.source_filepath)
source_filename = InventoryReport.xlsx

destination_filename = rf"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')}_{source_filename}"
destination_filename = 2024-07-18-15-35_InventoryReport.xlsx

self.working_path = os.path.join(self.working_path,destination_filename)
self.working_path = \\ABCfile\ReconciliationReports\QA\2024-07-18-15-35_InventoryReport.xlsx

shutil.copy2(self.source_filepath,self.working_path)


I've read that the backwards and forward slashes are interchangable They are, in certain contexts -- such as calling the open() function.  But not in other contexts, such as constructing an external command to be called via os.system().

We can't help unless you show us the code.

Given you are working across Windows and Unix, your code would definitely benefit from the abstractions of pathlib. But the main problem is that the location of the share will be different on your unix jenkins machine. \\machine\share\path is a windows convention - it will have to be mounted somewhere else on the Jenkins host, so there's probably no way of avoiding "if unix/windows" logic unfortunately.
